# I'm trying to find an example of abstraction - one of the 4 pillars of OOP - in JavaScript. Is this one?

Tags: javascript

Is the fact that `color` is inaccessible to directly modify outwith function `F` an example of the principle of abstraction (one of the 4 pillars of OOP) in JavaScript?

```js
function F() {
  let color = "red"
  this.method = function() {console.log(color)}
}

o = new F();

o.method();

console.log(color) //returns undefined
```

Comment: color is undefined in the global scope

Comment: It's an example of a *closure*; I'm not sure what the word "abstraction" brings to the table here.

Comment: @Pointy I've modified the question to say I'm trying to find an example of abstraction - one of the 4 pillars of OOP - in JavaScript. Would you be able to provide or point to an example?

Comment: It's just an example of 'closure'.

Comment: This is how we can use JS functions prototyping and `this` [As a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_constructor) and it is the *old way* to create objects with custom methods in Javascript; Javascript didn't have *real* OOP characteristics until ES6 classes and `class`, it's a prototype language.

Answer (score 2):

If the four pillars are

- Abstraction
- Encapsulation
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism

then I would say: no, hiding `color` from direct access is *not* an example for *Abstraction*.

Instead, this seems to be a good example for data hiding, usually thought to be essential to proper *Encapsulation*.
You are

- hiding the inner state `color` and
- offering a use-case oriented method `method` which works with that state.

An example for Abstraction might be as simple as the fact that you are modeling complex real-world objects by a single class (!) with only the members of interest to describe the features (!).

Comment: Thanks @HeroWanders. Maybe it's better for me to think of abstraction more abstractly...just the idea that, for instance, you had a car class, you had a method that is simple for the user to do, like `.accelerate`, but actually there's loads of complex conditions and things to assess that the 'accelerate' method will work out for you (if you have fuel to accelerate, what speed you'll go, how much distance will you travel) that the user won't know about. Better idea?

Comment: I think that's a fine example.